# ownership issue

Tags: ownership

I've three partitions.

1. Filesystem
2. swap
3. For my documents

I can't access the third one, it says

```
you aren't the owner
```

How can I access my partition?

Comment: what is partition table for that 3d partition?

Comment: I "for my documents" your `/home/<your_user_name>`?

Answer (score 1):

In this case try the command `lsblk` to verify that the block partition exists.
Check if is mounted or not by using the command: `df -hT`

If it exists but there is no mounted at the mount point session, then you need to mount it.

If it's mounted under `/home`  then try to change the home file permission by using the command `setfacl`

```
lsblk
setfacl -m u:user_name :rwx    /home
```

Comment: is this your answer that solved your issue?

Comment: yes it did. exactly

Answer (score 0):

If you recently add this partition (not during the Ubuntu install process), you can easily add permissions to your own user.

```
sudo chown user:user /path/to/documents -R
```

You also should check if the partition is properly formated and mounted.

-R parameter means recursive change permissions of all current files in this directory and its sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file owner and group. Open a terminal  by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the command

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"
```

to correct the settings recursively.